# Modify products query using custom field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to show products on a category page using the custom field.

For example, I have custom filed 'members_access_role' (multi check) and try

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'action_product_query', 10, 2 );
function action_product_query( $q, $query ) {

    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query');

    $q->set( 'meta_query', array( array(
        'key'     => 'members_access_role',
        'value'   => 'wholesale',
        'compare' => 'IN',
    ) ) );

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

This doesnt work, i try change compare to 'LIKE', '=' but nothing too.

Answer (score 0):

Please replace function like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'action_product_query', 10, 2 );
function action_product_query( $q, $query ) {

    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query');

    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'       => 'members_access_role',
        'value'     => 'wholesale',
        'compare'   => 'IN'
    );

    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seems to be setting `meta_query` twice and the 2nd time you are setting it is exactly the same as you received using get method.

Here is one way to write it

```
function action_product_query( $q, $query ) {

    $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query');   //Get the query

    //Update the array.
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'members_access_role',
        'value'   => 'wholesale',
        'compare' => '=',
    );

    //Set the updated value below.
    $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
}
```